# What can I do if I lose my Yellow Card?

Tags: paperwork, health, lost-documents

Also known as [International Certificate of Vaccination or Prophylaxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carte_Jaune),

> The Carte Jaune or Yellow Card is an international certificate of vaccination (ICV). It is **issued by the World Health Organization.** It is recognised internationally **and may be required for entry to certain countries where there are increased health risks for travellers.** The Yellow Card should be kept in the holder's passport, as it is a medical passport of sorts.

I have a Yellow Card with ~7 vaccinations, including one for Yellow Fever. When I was getting vaccinated, the doctor only signed and stamped vaccinations in the card, I'm not sure if they registered it anywhere.

If I ever lose it, is there any way to request a copy from any global organization (like WHO)? Or would I have to do it in the same hospital that I was vaccinated? I don't think I can just use a (notarized) copy if I ever need it entering another country, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Anywhere or hospital. You just need to convince the doctor you already had them. No big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My family doctor has a separate record of my vaccinations. When I received a number of travel vaccinations at a separate clinic, the receptionist at my family doctor took a photocopy of the yellow card and added it to my records. Now my family doctor can easily re-create a yellow card for me at any time, including both vaccinations I got at her office and those I got at the clinic.

If you take a photograph of your existing card, it may make the process of persuading someone to make you a new one simpler. It may also substitute for the card in case of loss. In my experience (and I have not gone to places that demand a yellow fever vaccination) people only ask you if you're vaccinated and don't demand that you prove it. (Unless you're a small child registering to attend school, but that's not in scope for Travel.)

Comment: Makes sense, I thought it would be more complicated. My friend apparently wasn't let inside Colombia for not having the card (she has been travelling around a lot recently, maybe that makes a difference), so I think that sometimes you actually have to show it.

Answer (score 2):

My daughter lost hers (in fact it was stolen along with her purse).

This is in Germany. It was a huge task to get her a new one. First she got a new empty one from her own local doctor.

Then I had to go to the doctors she had while she lived here and get all the childhood and subsequent vaccinations stamped up. The pediatrician had retired but the new one had taken over his records, fortunately.

And the normal doctor still had the records but demanded a fee for stamping.

She had to send me the card and her insurance card by post and I had to get all this done and send it all back within 2 weeks, for some reason.

TLDR: make a photocopy of your vaccination card.